# Delphi fmx blocked message Dialog box

Tags: dialog, message, firemonkey

While using android app developed using java or android studio I discovered that the message dialog prompt stay execution of the next line until the dialog prompt is answered. I have been trying to do this using TDialogService.MessageDialog(AMessage, ADialogType, AButtons, ADefaultButton, 0, procedurexyz). While the prompt is on display, the next line is executed making the prompt useless as the user was suppose to decide the next action. I need help from anyone to get an active block message dialog prompt.

Comment: blocking dialogs not supported in Android. Use callback functions.

Comment: What version of Delphi? FMX changes between versions, and the one  you're using is relevant.

Comment: @kami do you mean callback such as   TDialogService.MessageDialog(AMessage, ADialogType, AButtons, ADefaultButton, 0,
    // Use an anonymous method to make sure the acknowledgment appears as expected.
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      case AResult of
        { Detect which button was pushed and show a different message }
        mrYES: ShowMessage('You chose Yes');
        mrNo: ShowMessage('You chose No');
      end;
    end);
because I keep wondering how then is it done or achieved in java

Comment: @Ken am using Delphi 10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your suggestion @Kami I came up with this and its working very well for me, though am open to suggestions or additions.

```
function MsgBox(const AMessage: string; const ADialogType: TMsgDlgType; const AButtons: TMsgDlgButtons;
    const ADefaultButton: TMsgDlgBtn ): Integer;
var
    myAns: Integer;
    IsDisplayed: Boolean;
begin
    myAns := -1;
    IsDisplayed := False;
```

```
While myAns = -1 do
Begin
    if IsDisplayed = False then
    TDialogService.MessageDialog(AMessage, ADialogType, AButtons, ADefaultButton, 0,
            procedure (const AResult: TModalResult)
            begin
                myAns := AResult;
                IsDisplayed := True;
            end);

    IsDisplayed := True;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
End;

Result := myAns;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Embarcadero documentation says](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Dialogs.MessageDlg), that on Android platform you can use only non-blocking calls for `ShowMessage`, `MessageDialog`, `myForm.ShowModal` and etc.

To get "blocking" mode you can use workaround, like this:

```pascal
function myMessageDialog(const AMessage: string; const ADialogType: TMsgDlgType;
  const AButtons: TMsgDlgButtons; const ADefaultButton: TMsgDlgBtn): Integer;
var
  mr: TModalResult;
begin
  mr:=mrNone;
  // standart call with callback anonimous method
  TDialogService.MessageDialog(AMessage, ADialogType, AButtons,
    ADefaultButton, 0,
    procedure (const AResult: TModalResult) 
    begin 
      mr:=AResult 
    end);

  while mr = mrNone do // wait for modal result
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  Result:=mr;
end;
```